# Implementation of bitmask in Python Selectors module

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python [Selectors](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/selectors.py) module, there's a bitmask which can be `EVENT_READ` or `EVENT_WRITE` and the implementation is:

```
EVENT_READ = (1 << 0)
EVENT_WRITE = (1 << 1)
```

Is there any specific reason for using `1 << 0` and `1 << 1` other than making sure `EVENT_READ`, `EVENT_WRITE`, `EVENT_READ | EVENT_WRITE`, `EVENT_READ & EVENT_WRITE` will have different values?

Comment: That's not a good enough reason? I think that's a more readable bitflag implementation than, say, `EVENT_READ = 1`, `EVENT_WRITE = 2`

Comment: I guess the author wanted to make clear which bit has which function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more obvious when there are more than two bits.  This convention has been used for a long time in C, for example:

```c
#define XawPRSliderX            (1 << 0)
#define XawPRSliderY            (1 << 1)
#define XawPRSliderWidth        (1 << 2)
#define XawPRSliderHeight       (1 << 3)
#define XawPRCanvasWidth        (1 << 4)
#define XawPRCanvasHeight       (1 << 5)
```

This way, it is more obvious that these are individual bits and where they are placed, especially if there unused bits in-between or bits which are interpreted as a multi-bit integer.

Comment: `these are individual bits and where they are placed` that's very nice explanation sir! Thank you!